# Has Superman ever dominated over other metahumans?

Tags: dc, superman

In the game "Injustice - Gods Among Us", an alternate-universe Superman dominated over Earth and installed a dictatorship very much Stalin-like.

It showed that he had got the support from some metahumans, but most follow him much by fear.

Has Superman ever defeated a *united* group of superbeings such as Flash, Green Lantern, Wonder Woman, etc?

Comment: Since it clearly happened, clearly it can happen

Comment: But it's canon? I take I:GAU as an "what-if" type of story...

Comment: I suggest you change "Can Superman..." to "Has Superman ever..." to avoid having the question closed as "primarily opinion based".

Comment: Done, @WadCheber.

Comment: Boom.  That trick always works.

Comment: The last edit show the problem of me constructing an period in english thinking in portuguese....

Comment: the answer is: not in the canon (which only includes New 52 until now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Justice League Vol.1 #63 (1968) The Key mind controls the Justice League into fighting Superman. Superman knocks the Justice League unconscious. Superman defeats: 
Aquaman, 
Atom, 
Batman, 
Flash, 
Green Arrow, 
Green Lantern, 
Hawkman, 
and Wonder Woman